# Set-AzApplicationGatewaySku doesn't actually change settings?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-application-gateway

I've a v1 standard application gateway in Azure, i'm trying to use Azure Runbook to scale it.
This is achieved using an alert action, to run the book, which does work.
However, the commands in the book, while executed (and showing output), don't seem to change the SKU of the Application Gateway.
There are no errors or warnings showing.

The account i'm using to run the script has "Contributor" on the Application Gateway, and "Reader" on the subscription it resides in.

Here is the simple powershell script i'm running:

```
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
$connectionResult = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $connection.TenantID -ApplicationId $connection.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint

$AppGw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name "ag-gw1" -ResourceGroupName "applicationgateway-test"
Set-AzApplicationGatewaySku -ApplicationGateway $AppGw -Name "Standard_Large" -Tier "Standard" -Capacity 4
```

I've tried modifying the -Name, and -Capacity variables, with no effect. I've tried to run the runbook manually, too.

EDIT: I have tried to run this manually via Azure Console, and it does not work there either, but appears to work. (i.e. no errors, warnings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, once you've modified the Gateway's SKU, you need to commit it. To do so, you use the 'Set-AzApplicationGateway' command.

Final code would be (note the last line):

```
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
$connectionResult = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $connection.TenantID -ApplicationId $connection.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint
    
$AppGw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name "ag-gw1" -ResourceGroupName "applicationgateway-test"
$AppGw = Set-AzApplicationGatewaySku -ApplicationGateway $AppGw -Name "Standard_Large" -Tier "Standard" -Capacity 4
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $AppGw
```